# Using the same Entity in two different persistence unit

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

i have two database ( dababase_sales_1 and dababase_sales_2) with the same table "sales"
i created the Entity "Sales" (com.model.Sales)

then 2 persistence unit :

```
 <persistence-unit name="sales_1_PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
   <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.model.Sales</class>
    <class>com.model.SalesPK</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dababase_sales_1"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="myuser"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypasswrod"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size" value="1000"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="OFF" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

  <persistence-unit name="sales_2_PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.model.Sales</class>
    <class>com.model.SalesPK</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dababase_sales_2"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="myuser"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypasswrod"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size" value="1000"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="OFF" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

this is my POM

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
      
     
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      
      
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

but when i compile with maven i get this error :

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project MyProject: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: **Attempt to recreate a file for type com.model.SalesPK_** -> [Help 1]

i tried to remove

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

but nothing..
i cannot understand the reason...

Comment: no suggestions?

Comment: I'm not saying this is the solution but removing `<exclude-unlisted-classes>` won't change it to false because the default is true.

Comment: You did not post your whole pom.xml but it could also caused by the metamodel generator if you have this dependency in the pom.